# How to open a dialog when I click a button?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a button and I would like to open a dialog when pressed. This is my code:

```
Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more);
more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), agones.class);
        //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("hi");
        alertDialog.setMessage("this is my app");

        alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // here you can add functions
        }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: add this to your code alertDialog.show();

Comment: The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this).create();

Comment: the method setButton() is deprecated in android 4.4

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As @Roflcoptr has said, you haven't called `alertDialog.show()` method. thus your dialog doesn't appear.

Here's your edited code:

```
Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more);
more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), agones.class);
        //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(<YourActivityName>this).create(); //Read Update
        alertDialog.setTitle("hi");
        alertDialog.setMessage("this is my app");

        alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // here you can add functions
           }
        });

        alertDialog.show();  //<-- See This!
    }

});
```

if you write `this` instead of `<ActivityName>.this`, then it is going to take the reference of `View.OnClickListener` since `this` is currently being accessed inside it. You need to give your Activity's name there.

Comment: my problem it that eclipse hights the new AlertDialog.Builder and says that is undefined in the onClick

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this).create();

Comment: while creating just dont give as this instead give myActivity.this ....... it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Ganapathy I just couldn't notice it. so Im editing it to correct it.

Comment: `alertDialog.setButton("Continue..", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              // here you can add functions
           }
        });`  Is deprecated

Answer (score 11):

Your dialog isn't displayed, because you don't call [AlertDialog#show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#show()).

Answer (score 1):

[Aman Alam's souliton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850534/11211963) is good, but the `.setButton()` part gave me an error. So I implemented it in kotlin and fixed the error.

### Kotlin

```
    val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

    dialog.setTitle("Title")
          .setMessage("Write your message here.")
          .setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, whichButton ->
               // DO YOUR STAFF
          }
         .setNegativeButton("NO") { dialog, whichButton ->
               // DO YOUR STAFF 
               // dialog.close()
          }

    dialog.show()
```

[image: The result of the code]

More about dialogs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Answer (score -2):

```
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setMessage("this is message");
            builder.setTitle("this is title");

            //Setting message manually and performing action on button click
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to close this application ?");T
            //This will not allow to close dialogbox until user selects an option
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "positive button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //builder.finish();
                        }
                    });
             builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //  Action for 'NO' Button
                            Toast.makeText(this, "negative button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            //Creating dialog box
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            //Setting the title manually
            //alert.setTitle("AlertDialogExample");
            alert.show();
```