# Dialog window onclick Button

Tags: java, android, dialog

Please tell me I think problem in return.
I have a button and I would like to open a dialog when pressed.

This is my code:

```
 private void settinglistners() {
    shwdlg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure")
                    .setTitle("Delete")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });
            return builder.create();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can add more than one tag! Tagging your question with the programming language you use is a smart thing to do.

Comment: Your methods are `void` meaning that they cannot return anything. Is this Android? Then also tag this with Android.

Comment: Yes This is Android.

Comment: Thanks your answer is helpful.

Comment: check this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850493/open-a-dialog-when-i-click-a-button..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115758/how-do-i-display-an-alert-dialog-on-android

Answer (score 0):

use ".show()" after creating Dialog like this

```
private void settinglistners() {
shwdlg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure")
                .setTitle("Delete")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        return builder.create().show();

    }
});
```

}

i think this will helpful to you