# How to create alert dialog on button when it is clicked?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am trying to develop a small app as a part of my exam. Basically, I have a button that goes to a webpage and I want an alert dialog to pop up when the button is clicked and before the web page opens. This is what I have so far:

MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    webViewAndroidWeekly();

}


private void webViewAndroidWeekly (){
    Button btnWebpage = findViewById(R.id.btnwebpage);
    btnWebpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://androidweekly.net/"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for using this app! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

}

The button works and it opens the webpage so that part is set. I created a separate java class for the alert dialog and tried to implement it to work but I can't figure it out.

Dialog class:

public class InternetWarningDialog extends DialogFragment {

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setIconAttribute(android.R.attr.alertDialogIcon);
    builder.setTitle("Go to WebPage");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to proceed to webpage? This may incur additional charges based on your mobile data plan!");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    return alertDialog;
}
```

}

Comment: Duplicate of [open a dialog when i click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850493/open-a-dialog-when-i-click-a-button)

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What happens when you run this? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create this method in mainActivity ...... Call this showDialog() method in your main Activity where you want

```
public void showDialog(){

        InternetWarningDialog exampleDialog = new InternetWarningDialog();
        exampleDialog.show(getFragmentManager(),"Internet Dialog");

    }
```

If its works accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have created the **AlertDialog**, but to get the Alert dialog view use the method **show()** on **AlertDialog.Builder** as shown below

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any call for **AlertDialog**. You need to add the call for AlertDialog along with AlertDialog.show() and then open the webpage if the user clicks on Yes.

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
builder.show();
```

A familiar question has already been asked before. Please refer this 
[open a dialog when i click a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850493/open-a-dialog-when-i-click-a-button)